# Arduino run servo for N seconds with the possibility to interrupt

Tags: arduino

I'm a web developer and this is my first time coding for Arduino so I might not be able to express myself very clearly, but I'll try.

I am trying to do this:

- pins 8 and 9 come into contact and the servo turns from position A into postion B
- after a delay of 5000 ms, the servo goes back to position A

This works fine. However, I'm trying to introduce one more condition for the servo. I want to constantly read `val` (`analogueRead` of `potpin`) and if it's lower than 500, I want the servo to go back from position B to position A, but only temporarily, until `val` is back to >499 (all inside the 5000 ms interval).

I can easily achieve one or the other, but I'm having difficulties making the two work together. In the code below, everything works fine for the interval. I connect the pins, servo goes to position B, but when `val` changes (I know it's changed because I tried printing the values to the monitor), it doesn't happen. After the first `loop` reevaluation, it starts working and the servo responds to the changing `val`, but then that messes up the 5000 ms interval and servo does not go back to position A at the end.

This is my code:

```
#include <Servo.h>     
Servo myservo;
int potpin = 0;  // analog pin used to connect the potentiometer
int val;    // variable to read the value from the analog pin

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(8, INPUT_PULLUP);      //pin 8 forced to HIGH when there is no external input
  myservo.attach(9);           //attaches the servo on pin 9 to the     servo object
  myservo.write(60);           //tells servo to go to 60 degree position
}

void loop()
{
  while(digitalRead(8) == HIGH)
  {
    val = analogRead(potpin);

    if (val > 499) {
      myservo.write(60);
    } else {
      myservo.write(150);
    }
  }

  myservo.write(150);
  delay(5000);
}
```

I'm guessing my approach is simply wrong, but as I said, this is my first encounter with Arduino.

Comment: if your "potpin" variable is constantly changed by some external routine like interrupt or another thread, you are supposed to declare it as "volatile" so that your main thread is aware when its contents are changed

Comment: @mangusta potpin is fixed, just the `val` changes. Maybe I didn't write that very clearly, I'll edit.

Comment: but you're reading the "val" from analog "potpin", isn't it expected to change its value?

Comment: @mangusta the `potpin` itself is connected to A0 input and that doesn't change. What changes are the values read from the potentiometer connected to A0. Does that mean that `potpin` is changing? If I only leave the `val` in the loop and reevaluate it every 15 ms (for example), without the `digitalRead(8)` while loop altogether, the servo reacts OK to the changing `val`.

Comment: Your problem is that during the 5 seconds nothing else can happen. That Arduino `delay` is a blocking function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you want to do something inside the 5 second window but you used:

```
delay(5000);
```

which tells the Arduino to do NOTHING for 5 seconds.  During that time that it is doing nothing it isn't reading pins or moving servos.  Instead you should use the millis() timer to keep up with how long it has been since you started your routine.  That way the loop function can keep running and reading pins and moving servos.  See the "Blink Without Delay" example and any of the hundreds of tutorials on how it works for some inspiration on how to do this with non-blocking code.